# Running docker container on nanoPI leads to "exec format error"

Tags: docker, arm, docker-compose, nanopi

The goal is to run docker containers on my nanoPI in the same manner as on a ubuntu server machine.

I have recently run into the following error when attempting `docker run -it kylemanna/openvpn`:

**`standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "exec format error"`**

I also get the same error when executing `docker-compose` using the [container approach](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-as-a-container)

Since I get the problem whether I use docker compose or not, I am starting to think that the error might be my usage of docker on the nanoPI.  It may not be supported in the same way.

However, I can execute other containers/images just fine, `hello-world`, `ubuntu`, etc.

How do I go about determining the cause of this error? Where is the source code for `standard_init_linux.go:185`? And, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What kernel version is your nanoPI running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error, I discovered that if I rebuilt the openvpn image directly from the [github repository](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn) on the machine with which the container would be run using (`docker build <url>`), then this error was resolved for the openvpn container but not (yet) for docker-compose.  I imagine rebuilding the docker-compose container will fix the issue with that one too.

This is most likely due to a binary not having been compiled for the machine type that I was using.

Source/Inspiration: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23865

Comment: Most images will be `amd64`